# How can I send facebook application requests using a customized popup?

Tags: facebook

I want a customized popup from which i want to send application request ?

How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can send app request via http graph api , that is just an http post ... so you can build your own interface for that see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/

```
<?php
```

$app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;
  $app_secret = YOUR_APP_SECRET;

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . $app_id .
    "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
    "&grant_type=client_credentials";

$app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$user_id = THE_CURRENT_USER_ID;

$apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    $user_id .
    "/apprequests?message='INSERT_UT8_STRING_MSG'" . 
    "&data='INSERT_STRING_DATA'&"  .
    $app_access_token . "&method=post";

$result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
  echo("App Request sent?", $result);
?>